# How to test binders/property editors used on spring 2.5 controllers

Tags: unit-testing, data-binding, spring-mvc

I have an annotated controller with a method that expects a model and a binding result

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST)
  public ModelAndView submit(@ModelAttribute(“user”) User user, BindingResult bindingResult) {
     //do something
}
```

How do I test the binding result? If I call the method with a user and a binding result then I'm not testing the binding process. I figure there myst be something that takes a MockHttpServletRequest and returns the model and the binding result, any suggestions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Are you trying to test the binding (which happens before this method would be called) or are you trying to test the "submit" handler method?

You can test the binding with something like this:

```
 @Test
    public void testHandlerMethod() {

        final MockHttpServletRequest request = new MockHttpServletRequest("post", "/...");
        request.setParameter("firstName", "Joe");
        request.setParameter("lastName", "Smith");

        final User user = new User();
        final WebDataBinder binder = new WebDataBinder(user, "user");
        binder.bind(new MutablePropertyValues(request.getParameterMap()));

        final ModelAndView mv = controllerTestInstance.submit(user, binder.getBindingResult());

        // Asserts...

    }
```

Comment: That's just what I was looking for, thanks! In my controller I do bunch of registerCustomEditor setup though, so I suppose that should go on a class I can use from both the controller and the test?

Comment: If you're registering your custom editors in an initBinder method, you can just call that before you call the handler method in the test.

Answer (score 3):

You will probably find the [spring-test-mvc](https://github.com/SpringSource/spring-test-mvc) project very relevant to what you're trying to achieve. The project is usable today and is quite simple overall but there will be some changes along the way, so if you need a stable API then this isn't for you just yet.