# Spring @Controller Unittest @RequestMapping

Tags: java, unit-testing, spring, spring-mvc

Having a basic Spring Contoller i'd like to Unittest the Request Mapping (not the Method itself), if the `doCriticalStuff` Method is indeed called

```
package org.foo;

@Controller
public class HelloWorldController implements IHelloWorldController
{
   @RequestMapping(value = "/b/c/", method = RequestMethod.GET)
   public void doCriticalStuff(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response){
      //...
   }
}
```

Right now I'm doging this via `curl -X GET http://myIP:myPort/b/c/` from commandline in a manual way.
Any Ideas on how to automate it?
I could setup a Jetty instance, send a request and see if i get the expected response but isn't there an easier way provided by Spring?

Related Post: [How to test binders/property editors used on spring 2.5 controllers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2319845/how-to-test-binders-property-editors-used-on-spring-2-5-controllers)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd use a AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter and call adapter.handle. Just send in mock request and response objects along with your controller and spring should take care of the rest.